# Is it possible to iterate through several enum classes?

Tags: java, enums

I have three enum classes. I want to somehow put these in an array, loop through the array and call the same method in each enum class. Is this possible in Java?

It seems to me you can't place enum types in an array structure (unless i've missed how).

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "put [enum classes] in an array?" Are the methods static? Show us the code that you tried.

Comment: Enum[] or Object[] and you can put anything inside, if you need a common method, just define an interface.

Answer (score 4):

Let each enum type implement a **common interface** that has the **common method** that you want into invoke. You can now cast each enum, while iterating, to this common interface and call the method. Also look at [EnumSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)

Comment: I did try the common interface route but it doesn't work in my situation. I have static methods inside my enum classes which I need to call.

Comment: @user649716 let the common method implementation call the static methods in each of the enum types

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example with 2 enums and using reflection:

```
enum Colour{
    RED,
    BLUE,
    GREEN;

    public void foo(){
        System.out.println("COLOUR");
    }
}

enum Fruit {
    APPLE,
    BANANA,
    PEAR;

    public void foo(){
        System.out.println("FRUIT");
    }
}
```

You can put the classes into an array and use reflection to call a method for each enum constant:

```
//create an array
Class[] arr = new Class[2];
arr[0] = Colour.class;
arr[1] = Fruit.class;

//call the foo method
for(Class c : arr){
    Method m = c.getMethod("foo", null);
    for(Object o : c.getEnumConstants()){
        System.out.println("Invoking foo on:" + o);
        m.invoke(o, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If, by enum classes, you mean three different enums, each with their own elements, then you can use an array of type `Enum[]`. If you mean three items from a single enum, let's call it `enum X`, then you would put them in an array of type `X[]`.

If you are trying to call a standard Enum function on each one, then you should be all set. If you need to call your own function on them, and are going with an array of `Enum[]`, you'll either need to use reflection or have them all implement the same interface.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case. I have three separate enum classes. I can't place these inside an Enum[] because they can not be resolved to a variable - or be initialized.