# How to iterate through several Enums within a class

Tags: java, enums

I have a class with 70 enums.  I would like to iterate through the enums and just output the constants saved in each enum. it looks like this:

```
public class A {
    public enum One{
        ABC, DEF,
    }
    . 
    .
    .
    public enum Seventy{
        ASAS, SDDSDS,
    }
}
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354923/is-it-possible-to-iterate-through-several-enum-classes). But the question and suggested solutions are for 3 enums only. Is there an easier way than just hardcoding each enum's name into an array? Maybe there's already a java solution, like  `getAllMethods()` that I dont know of??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "70 enums"? Is that 1 enum class with 70 values or 70 classes with several values each?

Comment: @JoachimSauer, Hey Joachim, 70 classes of type Enum, so your second guess :). I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        Arrays.stream(A.class.getDeclaredClasses()).forEach(e ->
            Arrays.stream(e.getDeclaredFields())
                    .filter(Field::isEnumConstant)
                    .forEach(System.out::println));
```